# How to scale UDP read throughput?

Tags: linux

Setup: Two linux (CentOS 6) servers connected back-to-back over a dedicated GigE link. Each server with 24 cores and 32GB RAM

Client: Simulator shooting UDP packets as fast as it could in one thread. Each packet size is 256 bytes. I see that the maximum throughput is ~200,000 packets/sec.

Server: Receive packets on the UDP socket in one thread and perform light-weight parsing. I see that the maximum throughput is ~200,000 packets/sec, with CPU one 1 core about at 85% utilization during processing. There is no packet loss, the receive buffer is set to 128M just in case.

Now I have 23 additional cores i would like to use, but as soon as i add one more thread for receiving data on the server side and a client thread for sending data on the client side over a dedicated socket, I see a lot of packet loss on the server side.

The server threads are completely independent of each other and do not block except for I/O. They are not contending on the socket either as each one of them sucks packets off of their own UDP sockets.

I see the following behavior:

1. The CPU is about 85% on each core and a process called ksoftirqd/xx using about 90% if an additional core.
2. I am loosing packets, the throughout drops down on each thread to about 120,000 packets/sec

Google says that ksoftirqd uses CPU to handle soft interrupts and heavy system calls (UDP read) can be one of the reason for high CPU usage for this kernel thread.

I repeated the experiment by pinning my process to a bunch of cores on the same physical socket and I see that the performance improved to 150,000 packets/sec with still some considerable packet loss.

Is there a way i can improve the scalability of my program and minimize packet loss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, at 200,000 packets per second with 256 (data?) bytes per packet, once you consider UDP, IP, and Ethernet overhead, you're running at nearly half the capacity, counting bandwidth alone, of your gigabit link. At the packet-per-second rates you're pushing, many switches (for example) would fall over.

Second, you're probably being killed by IRQs. Better network cards have tunables to let you trade off fewer IRQs for increased latency (they only interrupt once every N packets). Make sure you have that enabled. (One place to check is the module parameters for your ethernet card.)

Comment: Thank You derobert. In this case the servers are connected back-to-back. There is no switch involved. I do agree that i am pushing it to the limit but that is the whole point of my experiment. 

Is there an example you can suggest for a specific card? Any pointers on where to look will help me. I can test and re-post. Is there any difference between IRQ handling and SoftIRQ handling? I am a dummy when it comes to the kernel. Any comments will help me figure out the issue here. Thanks.

Comment: @Ravi: do a `vmstat 1`, the `in` column is the number of Hardware IRQs received per second, for the network card their processing usually consists of getting some frames from the network card into the kernel and notify the kernel to process them, which the kernel will do on a SoftIRQ (the net softirq). You want to coalesce work, and avoid constantly interrupting useful work with hard IRQs, that's what interrupt mitigation is for.

Comment: @RaviChamarthy: I've never actually tried to push the packet-per-second limit, but my guess would be to try Intel cards. `modinfo e1000` or `modinfo e1000e` will give you the options, and Documentation/network/e1000.txt (etc.) will hopefully explain. I'd use `procinfo -n 5 -Sd` (5 is the refresh time, use whatever you want).

Comment: @derobert thank you for your guidance. My card is Intel GigE ethernet card and the module is e1000 as you suggested. I set the InterruptThrottleRate to 5000 interrupts per second and could reduce the CPU utilization of ksoftirqd/xx to 5% of 1 core and increase the packet processing to an 180,000 packets per thread with minimal only 5% packet loss. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the kernel receive buffer, but be aware that it won't help if the IRQs eat all your CPU.

```
int n = 1024 * 512; //experiment with it
if (setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &n, sizeof(n)) == -1) {
  //oops... check this
}
```

You should also set the maximum receive buffer to a large value so the kernel doesn't limit your setting:

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=<value>
```

Comment: Well I already set my receive buffer to 128M using sysctl. It did not work. I need to figure out whats causing the contention when i have tons of capacity. It is either the network card or the socket interface as i profiled my code for any contention.

Answer (score -2):

If your application requires 200,000 packets per second, either your protocol is not well designed, or you're doing something else wrong.

Where do the 200k packets come from? Different hosts across the internet? Maybe you should load-balance it or something?

As derobert pointed out, 200k packets per second represents a lot of bandwidth which will be very costly on the internet, you should probably consider a protocol redesign.

Comment: The traffic is between back-to-back connected servers. The protocol is not under my control. Its a collection application and i need to collect as much as the source generates. I am pushing for a protocol redesign, in the mean time i need to solve the scale issue. Thanks.